# How to export font information for a specific PSD file for use in writing CSS

Tags: adobe-photoshop, css, plugin

I'm doing front-end dev, so this question comes from that perspective.  When I receive a `.psd` I manually go through each font in the design, click on it, then use the character panel to get the font, color, size, kerning, etc.  Sometimes, I get a design that uses several different fonts (4+) with many variations of the same font (size, color, weight, etc.).  This is pretty tedious work... Is there anyway that Photoshop can export a list of all the used fonts and their variations? For example, a list like:

> Arial bold 16px black 
>   Arial regular 14px black
>  
>   Arial regular 14px blue
>   Oswald 32px rgb(13,74,56)
>  ...

Any suggestions for this?  Further, if there is a plugin of sorts that will just lay this information over the elements that would be fantastic!

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure, you can use the ExtendScript Toolkit to investigate and manipulate Photoshop documents. For more info, [check the documentation](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/photoshop/scripting.html) or search around the various PS scripting forums.

Based on the script in [this article](http://tomkrcha.com/?p=3743), I whipped up the following script. For every text layer in a `PSD` file, it will print the font, font-size, and fill-color to the javascript console:

```
function run(){
    var layerSets = app.activeDocument.layerSets;
    dumpLayerSets(layerSets);

    $.writeln("Top-level layers:");
    dumpLayers(app.activeDocument.layers);

}

function dumpLayerSets(layerSets){
    $.writeln("--- Processing...");
    var len = layerSets.length;
    for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
         var layerSet = layerSets[i];
         //$.writeln(layerSet.name);
         dumpLayers(layerSet.artLayers);
    }
}

function dumpLayers(layers){
    var len = layers.length;
    for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
         var layer = layers[i];
         if(layer.kind==undefined){
                continue;
         }
        if(layer.kind == LayerKind.TEXT){
         $.writeln('font: '+ layer.textItem.font +' font-size: ' + layer.textItem.size + ' color: #' + layer.textItem.color.rgb.hexValue);
        }
    }
}
run();
```

To test, open a document with text layers in Photoshop. Open the ExtendScript Toolkit and link it to your Photoshop instance. Paste the code above into the workspace and hit the run button.

[image: ExtendScript Toolkit screenshot]

Based on this file:
[image: Text Layered PSD file]

I received the following output:

```
--- Processing...
Top-level layers:
font: MyriadPro-It font-size: 144 pt color: #0000FF
font: MyriadPro-Bold font-size: 144 pt color: #00FF00
font: MyriadPro-Regular font-size: 144 pt color: #FF0000
Result: undefined
```

Comment: I had _no_ idea you could access Photoshop with JavaScript!  Thanks for this, I ran it and it output 17 different font variations - very useful indeed!

Answer (score 2):

the photoshop plugin [SpecKing](http://wuwacorp.com/specking/) has an option to show/generate all typographic specifications within your photoshop file - could that help? I haven't tried it myself, but it looks useful.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that CSS font matching is based on the font *family* name, not the fullname (e.g. "Myriad Pro Bold") or the PostScript name (e.g. "MyriadPro-Bold").  Chrome/Safari on OSX will match the PostScript name but that's non-standard behavior, it won't work in Firefox and it won't work in any Windows-based browser.  For use in CSS you'll need to map the PostScript name to family/weight/style combinations, so instead of MyriadPro-BoldIt:

```
font-family: Myriad Pro;
font-weight: bold;
font-style:  italic;
```

etc.

Answer (score 1):

There are plugins/services that allow you to extract this (and other information) from PSDs:

- [Avocode](http://avocode.com/)
- [CSSHat](https://csshat.com/)
- [Project Parfait](https://projectparfait.adobe.com/)
- [CSS3PS](http://css3ps.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I know this was asked a while ago but there's also a website, [PSDFonts.com](http://psdfonts.com), that can provide this information for you (although it won't provide an overlay).